# Does $\int_0^x \tan\left(\frac\pi4e^{-t}\right) dt $ have a horizontal asymptote?

Tags: calculus, limits, asymptotics

Let $$f(x) = \int_0^x  \tan\left(\frac\pi4e^{-t}\right) dt.$$

Does $f(x)$ have a horizontal asymptote? If so, what value does it tend to?

Also, what are the necessary and sufficient conditions on which a function has horizontal asymptotes for a function that cannot be defined by elementary function, i.e., like above?

Comment: Since $\int f(x)\; dx$ refers to an infinite family of functions, what do you mean by "what value does it tend to?"

Comment: Hello, yeah sorry. The exact integral I was looking at was the finite integral from 0 to x with the variable inside the integral being t ( I wasn't sure if I could replicate this on here) https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=integral+from+0+to+x+of+tan%28%28pi%2F4%29%28e%5E-t%29%29+dt (as shown here)

Comment: $\int_0^{\infty } \tan \left(\frac{\pi  e^{-x}}{4}\right) \, dx\approx 0.849$. Hope this can help

Comment: ^^ Approximating this integral for x = infinity should give us and approximate value for f(x) at the horizontal asymptote. So i guess its approximately 0.849, I wonder if there is an exact way to write this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The function $f(x) = \int_0^x \tan\left(\frac{\pi}{4} e^{-t}\right)\; dt$ does have a horizontal asymptote.  I don't know the exact value, but it is somewhere between $0$ and $\frac{\sqrt{2} \pi}{4}$.

To see this, first note that on $(0,\infty)$, $\frac{\pi}{4} e^{-t}$ takes values in $(0,\pi/4)$, and that on $(0,\pi/4)$, $\tan$ is strictly positive.  This implies that $f$ is strictly increasing on $(0,\infty)$.

Second, because $(\tan x)' = \sec^2 x$ is bounded above by $\sqrt{2}$ on $(0,\pi/4)$, it follows that $\tan(x) \leq \tan(0) + \sqrt{2}x = \sqrt{2}x$ on $(0,\pi/4)$.  Substituting $x = \frac{\pi}{4} e^{-t}$ gives $\tan \left( \frac{\pi}{4} e^{-t}\right) \leq \frac{\sqrt{2}\pi}{4}e^{-t}$ on $(0,\infty)$.  Integrating this inequality on $(0,x)$ gives $$f(x) \leq \frac{\sqrt{2}\pi}{4} \int_0^x e^{-t}\; dt \leq \frac{\sqrt{2}\pi}{4} \int_0^\infty e^{-t}\; dt = \frac{\sqrt{2}\pi}{4}.$$

So, $f$ is increasing and bounded above.  It follows that $\lim_{x\rightarrow \infty} f(x)$ exists, so $f(x)$ has a horizontal asymptote between $0$ and $\frac{\sqrt{2}\pi}{4}$.

Lastly, note that the other antiderivatives of $\tan\left(\frac{\pi}{4}e^{-t}\right)$ are vertical shifts of $f(x)$, so they also have horizontal asymptotes.

Comment: Thank you, this is really clear and makes perfect sense!!

Comment: $y=0.848967130724895$ is approximately the horizontal asymptote

Answer (score 0):

Horizontal asymptotes imply that the derivative of a differentiable function tends to zero at +- infinity, that is, we get a necessary condition. We can see that plus infinity is a case for the considered function.

Generally, I'd study the behavior of the [Cauchy sequences](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy_sequence) for a given function. If they are dense (converge to the same limit for arbitrary intervals and sufficiently large x), asymptote detected.

As for the precise value,apart from initial conditions, I'd do a [contour integration](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Residue_theorem#An_integral_along_the_real_axis) over the real line to find it. But you'll need, say, the function value at -infinity in order to know its asymptote value.
A simple estimate can be achieved via [saddle point-like](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Method_of_steepest_descent) analysis

Comment: I don't think your first sentence is correct.  For example, consider $f(x) = \sin(x^3)/x$.  This has a horizontal asymptote of $y=0$, but $f'(x) = 3x\cos(x^3) - \frac{\sin(x^3)}{x}$, whose supremum is unbounded.  Second, I don't think it's sufficient, even for $C^\infty$ functions.  For example, the function $f(x) = \ln(x)$ is unbounded as $x\rightarrow\infty$, and yet $f'(x) = \frac{1}{x}\rightarrow 0$ as $x\rightarrow \infty$.

Comment: Nice, but I was thinking about differentiable functions. Clearly your first one is not at x->Infty. As for the second claim, I'll edit it